# Android webview javascript interface not working from Angular 12

Tags: android, angular, android-webview, hybrid-mobile-app

We have loaded ionic/angular site inside the Android using webview.

It was worked till Angular 11 version without any issues. Recently we have tried the Angular version upgrade to 13+.

From that, we are not able to access the javascript interface object. Code sample below.

**Android** object return null after angular migration. If downgraded back to Angular 11, it is working fine.

**No changes in native code**

Added below script in index.html

```html
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```